# Align text with glyph

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the text in span with the quote glyph. `display: -moz-grid;` will create the expected behavior but will ignore the div with, and it's not a cross browser solution.

Any another way?

```
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
  <span>Some random text Some rando random text Some random text Some random text Some random text Some random text</span>
</div>

div {
  width: 400px
}

span {
  display: -moz-grid;
}
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/k1byph3h/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you going for a hanging indent?  You can do that by creating a [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context).  The below method uses `overflow:hidden`, which usually has no visible effect on elements without set widths and heights; but you can use any one of the methods listed on that MDN page.

```css
div {
  width: 400px
}

i.fa {
  float:left;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
}
span {
  overflow:hidden;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
  <span>Some random text Some rando random text Some random text Some random text Some random text Some random text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: why overflow:hidden; works in that way? The combination of block with hidden seems some type of black magic to me. Well, apparently flex or table works too.

Comment: @user2990084 It has to do with how floats interact with elements in the DOM.  At times it does seem a little arbitrary, but the block formatting context is pretty established in the spec, so you can rely on it being fairly consistent.  It comes down to how floats operate. The official spec can be found here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting